# Show only HTTP traffic in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

How can I filter out traffic that is not HTTP in Wireshark, so that it shows me only HTTP traffic, but not, TCP, DNS, SSDP, etc.

[image]

Comment: HTTP traffic usually *IS* TCP traffic; it's not as if HTTP and TCP are at the same network layer.  The Protocol column just shows the topmost protocol layer Wireshark understands; if a TCP packet just has an ACK and no data, or Wireshark doesn't know how to dissect the data, it'll show it as TCP, but if it does know how to dissect it, it'll show that protocol.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the filter field, type `http` (lowercase!). Tested with [WireShark Portable 1.10.7](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

[image]

#### Some basic  filters

- `!http` shows all traffic which is NOT http
- `ip.src != 196.168.1.1` shows traffic which is NOT from this IP source
- `ip.dst == 196.168.1.1` shows traffic to this IP destination
- `ip.addr == 196.168.1.1` shows all traffic which has the specific IP as source OR destination

Comment: OK, it's working, but it shows both http and ssdp fields, which is strange. When I tried typing just "ssdp", it said no such protocol exists.

Comment: What wireshark version do you use? The wireshark wiki says, that [you cannot filter for SSDP](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSDP). Workaround is `udp.dstport == 1900 && http`

Comment: Version 1.8.2. Also, when I typed "tcp" for filter, it showed TCP, TLSv1.1  and HTTP fields.

Comment: If you type "tcp" as the filter, it'll show all TCP traffic, whether it's HTTP running over TCP, SSL/TLS running over TCP, or something else running over TCP.

Comment: what if you only see protocol: 0x0800

Comment: ie I want to filter by http and don't see it

Answer (score 5):

To exclude SSDP/UDP: `http && tcp`

Credit: http://www.emtek.net.nz/blog/2013/03/17/wireshark-filter-http-only-exclude-ssdp-or-udp/

Comment: I have been trying to figure that one out for ages. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter "ip address" and e.g. "http protocol" you have to input:

```
ip.src==192.168.109.217&&http
```

without **spaces** between.